# Unable to render an element after changing the URL, need to refresh the page every time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am newbie to reactjs. I am trying get hit an API and try to render the response, It works fine for the first time but when I try to change the parameter of API the element does not render. However, URL get updated. If, I refresh the page, then It renders.

Initially get proper response and able to render News element and URL is ***http://localhost:3000/***
but, when try to select other category from dropdown menu URL is ***http://localhost:3000/health*** but neither hit an API nor render News element. But, if refresh this page ***http://localhost:3000/health*** it hit an API and render News element.

It works fine if I type the URL manually.

**EDIT:** I am trying to call API and want to display result. To hit the API I am using componentDidMount(). API contains query parameter called “category”.  (Categories are science, health and general).  End user can change the category by selecting value form dropdown which changes value of category.

Initially, home page render componentDidMount() execute and the give the response with category=general. After that, when I try to select other value form dropdown end of URL get changed, but it does not call API. Then, if I refresh the page, API hits and give new response.

**Current Workflow:**

1. Initial page load (Home Page) => (http://localhost:3000/) Getting data regarding **GENERAL** category.
2. After select health from **dropdown** => (http://localhost:3000/health) Getting data regarding **GENERAL** category.
3. On same **http://localhost:3000/health** after clicking refresh button of browser => Getting data regarding **HEALTH** category.

**Expected Workflow:**

1. Initial page load (Home Page) => (http://localhost:3000/) Getting data regarding **GENERAL** category.
2. After select health from **dropdown** => (http://localhost:3000/health) I should get data regarding **HEALTH** category.

**1) Navbar.js**

```
<ul className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="categoryDropdown">                                     
   <li><Link className="dropdown-item" to="/">General</Link></li>
   <li><Link className="dropdown-item" to="/health">Health</Link></li>
   <li><Link className="dropdown-item" to="/science">Science</Link></li>
</ul>
```

**2) App.js**

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/"  exact element={<News key="general" category={'general'} />} />
            <Route path="/health" exact element={<News key="health" category={'health'} />} />
            <Route path="/science" exact element={<News key="science" category={'science'} />} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

**3) News.js**

```
 async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}&apiKey=<MYAPIKEY>`
    await fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          totalRowCount: response.totalResults,
          articles: response.articles,
          isLoading: false
        })
      });
}

render() {
    // console.log('render')
    return (
      <div>
          <div className="container-fluid my-3">
            <div className="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center align-items-center">
              {this.state.articles.map((element) => {
                return <div key={element.url}>
                  <NewsItem title={element.title} description={element.description} imageUrl={element.urlToImage} newsUrl={element.url} />
                </div>
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

***NOTE: I am using class based component***

Comment: I guess async has no effect tmk on cDM method ... put a log inside it and see if it logs

Comment: I already tried, but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

The `News` component should also implement the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method to handle when the `country` prop value updates. I suggest just refactoring the logic into a function that is called in both `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`. Also, don't mix `async/await` with Promise chains.

Example:

```
fetchData = async () => {
  this.setState({ isLoading: true });

  const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}&apiKey=<MYAPIKEY>`;

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({
      totalRowCount: data.totalResults,
      articles: data.articles,
    });
  } catch(error) {
    ....
  } finally {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
    });
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchData();
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.country !== this.props.country ||
    prevProps.category !== this.props.category
  ) {
    this.fetchData();
  }
}

...
```

Comment: Thank you, @DrewReese, for giving the suggestion and your time. But still, it is not 
working.

Comment: @Prem *What* exactly isn't working? Can you clarify more precisely what the issue is? Can you edit your post to include a more complete and comprehensive [mcve]?